# how to make pixel level collision in Iphone

Tags: iphone

How to make pixel level collision in Iphone.

In j2me i able to make pixel level collision

```
Sprite s;
s.collidesWith(s1,true); //For pixel level collision
```

In Iphone i used:

```
CGRectInterSect(img1,img2);
```

How i make in Iphone.  Any samples for pixel level collision

Answer (score 0):

You can use a physics engine like **Chipmunk** or **Box2D**. It will be a lot easier for you.